# Why do I get the error 'Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}'?

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and iOS development but I am trying to download and parse data that is stored in a MySQL Database.

I keep getting the error:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

I have posted my code below but I don't think the problem is in the parseJSON function but instead in the actual download of the data as when I print the 'data' out it returns '<>'.

Here is my code:

```
//properties

weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

let urlPath: String = "http://localhost/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

// Function to download the incoming JSON data
func downloadItems(){
    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default


    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url)

    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionDataTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    self.data.append(data as Data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil{
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else{
        print("Data downloaded")
        print(data)
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}

func parseJSON(){

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options: []) as! NSMutableArray
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("**** sake its happened again \(error)")
    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let exerciseName = jsonElement["stationName"] as? String,
            let bodyPart = jsonElement["buildYear"] as? String
        {
            print(exerciseName, bodyPart)
            location.exerciseName = exerciseName
            location.bodyPart = bodyPart

        }

        locations.add(location)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items:locations)

    })
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the response is empty? What does your `print(data)` show?

Comment: try to do that in postman or somewhere else and check if something is really there

Comment: I have tried printing data and it returns <> 

When I view the url that I am using I get this returned:

'[
    {
        "Exercise_Id": "1",
        "Exercise_Name": "Barbell Curl",
        "Body_Part": "Arms"
    },'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially bad thing in your code:

```
//This method is not being called...
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionDataTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    self.data.append(data as Data) //<-This line adding self.data to self.data
}
```

There is no `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)` method which takes `URLSessionDataTask` as its second parameter. So, this method would never be called.

And inside the method, `self.data` is appended to `self.data`, so even if the method is called, `self.data` is still being empty...

You need to implement this method instead:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.data.append(data)
}
```

But if you want to do nothing other than accumulating received data, you have no need to use delegates.

And you are using forced casting in your `parseJSON()` method:

```
    jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options: []) as! NSMutableArray
```

without specifying `.mutableContainers` option. This also would crash your app.

And your code uses too much of `NSSomethings`.

---

With all such things fixed, you can get something like this:

```
//properties

weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

let urlPath: String =  "http://localhost/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

// Function to download the incoming JSON data
func downloadItems() {
    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to download data: \(error)")
        } else if let data = data {
            print("Data downloaded")
            print(data as NSData)
            //print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
            self.parseJSON(data: data)
        } else {
            print("Something is wrong...")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func parseJSON(data: Data){

    do {
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

            var locations: [LocationModel] = []

            for jsonElement in jsonResult {
                let location = LocationModel()

                //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
                if let exerciseName = jsonElement["stationName"] as? String,
                    let bodyPart = jsonElement["buildYear"] as? String
                {
                    print(exerciseName, bodyPart)
                    location.exerciseName = exerciseName
                    location.bodyPart = bodyPart

                }

                locations.append(location)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("bad JSON")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("**** sake its happened again \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping with my problem, this has fixed it perfectly!